# How to change email asp.net core identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to add a feature to my project so that the user can change their mail account whenever they want. If I change the email only and set it, the username property does not change, so the old email address must be used again when logging in (SetEmailAsync).

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeEmail(ChangeEmailModel item)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = XmlLangHtmlExtender.L("UserLogType_ChangeEmail");
        try
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.Email = item.Email;
                user.UserName = item.Email;
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                 // await _userManager.SetEmailAsync(user, item.NewEmail); 
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, XmlLangHtmlExtender.L("UserNotFound"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Logger.GetErrorMessage(e));
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Profile");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any concern about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We can [add an additional property called "OldEmail"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to your user model( ApplicationUser ). If you can create a new table to store the records of changing, then you can customize various limits according to your needs.

Then you sample code should like below

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeEmail(ChangeEmailModel item)
{
    ViewBag.Title = XmlLangHtmlExtender.L("UserLogType_ChangeEmail");
    try
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.OldEmail= item.Email;
            user.UserName = item.Email;
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            var result = await _userManager.SetEmailAsync(user, item.NewEmail); 
            // add history in the new table
            
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, XmlLangHtmlExtender.L("UserNotFound"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Logger.GetErrorMessage(e));
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```